# Nested "for" loop will not change variable within loop

Tags: python, for-loop, append

```
        for a in range(0,2):
            for x in range (0,16):
                bombs.append(((40*x),(40*a),39,39))
```

This is my first question on this site and i'm pretty new to python so any tips and simple explanation would be greatly appreciated!

As said in the title i cannot seem to change the "a" variable in the .append. The output i receive is this:

(0, 0, 39, 39)
(40, 0, 39, 39)
(80, 0, 39, 39)
(120, 0, 39, 39)
(160, 0, 39, 39)
(200, 0, 39, 39)
etc....

(0, 0, 39, 39)
(40, 0, 39, 39)
(80, 0, 39, 39)
(120, 0, 39, 39)
(160, 0, 39, 39)
(200, 0, 39, 39)
etc...

The first set is obviously correct but when it loops over again the variable stays at 0 instead of being the value of 40*a!

I'm hoping that i'm making a simple error! Thank you

update with full code:

```
def bomb():
    global bombs
    bombs=[]

    for a in range(0,2):
        for x in range (0,16):
            bombs.append(((40*x),(40*a),39,39))
            print bombs[x]
```

Comment: `[(0, 0, 39, 39), (40, 0, 39, 39), (80, 0, 39, 39), (120, 0, 39, 39), (160, 0, 39
, 39), (200, 0, 39, 39), (240, 0, 39, 39), (280, 0, 39, 39), (320, 0, 39, 39), (
360, 0, 39, 39), (400, 0, 39, 39), (440, 0, 39, 39), (480, 0, 39, 39), (520, 0,
39, 39), (560, 0, 39, 39), (600, 0, 39, 39), (0, 40, 39, 39), (40, 40, 39, 39),
(80, 40, 39, 39), (120, 40, 39, 39), (160, 40, 39, 39), (200, 40, 39, 39), (240,
 40, 39, 39), (280, 40, 39, 39), (320, 40, 39, 39), (360, 40, 39, 39), (400, 40,
 39, 39), (440, 40, 39, 39), (480, 40, 39, 39), (520, 40, 39, 39), (560, 40, 39,
 39), (600, 40, 39, 39)]`

Comment: This is the output when i ran your program and printed `bombs`. The value of a is changing alright :) since it is a nested loop it changes after 16 values as can be seen in `(0, 40, 39, 39)`

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem: http://ideone.com/DATDNd Is this really the whole code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are nested loops. Your inner loop

```
for x in range (0,16):
```

will iterate 16 times during the first iteration of the outer loop. Only after these 16 iterations where only `x` changes, will `a` change for the first time!

```
[..., (600, 0, 39, 39),  (0, 40, 39, 39), ...]
```

Comment: But the sample output in the question doesn't have `(0, 40, 39, 39)` in it.

Comment: Yes I know, sorry I just shortened the output in the question, but after the 16 iterations and it loops over again for the second time. "a" inside the .append still gives me a result of 0

Comment: @JackIndge Well, then you didn not just not post the relevant output, but also not all the relevant code ;)

Comment: Yeah, it would have helped if the OP mentioned that he was doing `print bombs[x]` for some reason.. :-)

Comment: Sorry to all, clearly it was doing what it was supposed to be doing but I was looking at the wrong output... as I said I'm pretty new to this! But thank you all for your help